# out of stock products change price magento

Tags: php, magento

We are working on a sit  and one of the requests is for customers to be able to add out of stock products to the shopping cart. However, the price for those out of stock products needs to be changed to $0.00 in the shopping cart. Can you help?

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: This is fairly simple by the use of an observer which is executed when the user adds an item to the cart. When the event happens you could check the stock level and override the quote items price so that's $0 if there is no stock, @Hassan is correct though, what have you tried, where's the code? Sorry, but we will not provide a working solution or help debug it if you don't show us that you've tried.Hopefully the above will set you on the right track to develop a base solution, but there are pitfalls in this method to be aware of. e.g. Purchase 10 days after add to cart when it's back in stock